# Is there a way to increase number of cookies per website in chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies

I am creating cookies to hold the filter data in each search page using javascript. At some point, the browser is not able to create any more cookies because of the restricted size of the cookies per website in chrome. So is there a way to increase number cookies per website in chrome

Comment: You could use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to store your data instead, it might be more appropriate.

Comment: I do not think you can change a browser setting from your site.. But you could use local storage, which has quite more space available.

Comment: How much cookie data are we talking about here …? Unless you have taken specific measures to set them for very limited routes only, shoveling heaps of data into them that gets send back to the server with every request would not be a very smart thing to do to begin with ...

Comment: seems like cookie is not a good idea to go with @CBore. localstorage sounds good. Thanks for the heads up